How to use x86-64 SIMD vector instructions and registers for polynomial evaluation
I need to write a x86-64 assembly function that uses x86 vector/SIMD instructions and the %ymm registers to evaluate this expression: x*(x*(a*x + b) + c) + d.
The function will have this signature: void map_poly_double_vec(double* input, double* output, uint64_t length, double a, double b, double c, double d) where a, b, c, and d are constant. The double* input argument is a pointer to an array of double x values to use to calculate the above expression.
The result will then be put into the output array in the corresponding position. I can assume the array length is divisible by 4.
I have already written this function using %xmm registers and have used vector instructions to create a dot product function but I am now a bit lost on how to approach this problem using the vector instructions. Any tips or help would be appreciated.
Here's the implementation of the function using %xmm registers and a dot product function using the vector instructions I am expected to use.
    .section .note.GNU-stack,""
    .global map_poly_double, dot_double_vec
    .text

dot_double_vec:
    vxorpd %xmm2, %xmm2, %xmm2
    vxorpd %ymm0, %ymm0, %ymm0
    vxorpd %ymm1, %ymm1, %ymm1
    mov $0, %rcx

ddv_loop:
    cmp %rdx, %rcx
    jae ddv_end

    vmovupd (%rdi, %rcx, 8), %ymm1
    vmulpd (%rsi, %rcx, 8), %ymm1, %ymm0

    vextractf128 $0x1, %ymm0, %xmm1
    vaddpd %xmm1, %xmm0, %xmm0
    vshufpd $0b01, %xmm0, %xmm0, %xmm1
    vaddsd %xmm1, %xmm0, %xmm0

    vaddsd %xmm0, %xmm2, %xmm2

    add $4, %rcx
    jmp ddv_loop

ddv_end:
    movq %xmm2, %xmm0
    ret

#######

map_poly_double:
    mov $0, %rcx

map_poly_double_loop:
    cmp %rcx, %rdx
    je map_poly_double_end

    pxor %xmm5, %xmm5

    movq (%rdi, %rcx, 8), %xmm4
    movq %xmm0, %xmm5
    mulsd %xmm4, %xmm5
    addsd %xmm1, %xmm5

    mulsd %xmm4, %xmm5
    addsd %xmm2, %xmm5

    mulsd %xmm4, %xmm5
    addsd %xmm3, %xmm5

    movq %xmm5, (%rsi, %rcx, 8)

    add $1, %rcx
    jmp map_poly_double_loop

map_poly_double_end:
    ret



You just need to duplicate your constants then switch everything over to vectors. Make sure you scale the pointers and adjust the counter properly. Where did you get stuck?

@Jester I got stuck/confused on how to use the %ymm registers to calculate the result, i.e. multiplying and adding with only the %ymm registers.

ymm is not different from xmm just twice as wide. Your task is to switch from scalars to vectors. E.g. instead of mulsd you want mulpd.

@Jester Wouldn't it be different with how the values are calculated since the ymm registers have more than one value within it and I need to do SIMD instructions? I might just be overthinking this lol

xmm also has space for more than one value. You just used scalar instructions such as mulsd (the s stands for scalar).

@Jester ohh okay, I think I'm understanding it now. Definitely just a problem of overthinking it, thank you!

That's not an efficient dot product!!  Accumulate each element of the product vector into separate elements of a vector register, summing once at the end.  You should be doing one vmulpd / vaddpd (or vfmadd231pd) per 2 loads, no shuffling in the inner loop just vertical SIMD.  See Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators) for more about efficient dot products, especially loop unrolling to hide FP latency is about a 4x speedup for data hot in cache

Re: SIMD polynomial evaluation: my answer on Why does this code execute more slowly after strength-reducing multiplications to loop-carried additions? optimizes data[i] = A*i*i + B*i + C; to run at one 32-byte vector store per clock on Skylake, doing 2x vaddpd per clock cycle (no multiplies since I used strength-reduction optimization to save work, with unrolling to hide the latency of the loop-carried dep chain that introduced).  Other answers have simpler techniques.

If you don't know how to vectorize, look at the compiler output and learn from the compiler. GCC has no trouble vectorizing this stuff properly. See here at .L5 on Godbolt

In C++, assuming your arrays are relatively long, I would do that math with the following code. Untested.
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <assert.h>

void map_poly_double_vec( const double* input, double* output,
    uint64_t length, double a, double b, double c, double d )
{
    // Broadcast coefficients into AVX vectors
    const __m256d av = _mm256_set1_pd( a );
    const __m256d bv = _mm256_set1_pd( b );
    const __m256d cv = _mm256_set1_pd( c );
    const __m256d dv = _mm256_set1_pd( d );

    // I can assume the array length is divisible by 4.
    assert( 0 == ( length % 4 ) );
    // Compute end pointers for both loops
    const uint64_t lengthAligned = length & ~( uint64_t )15;
    const double* const inputEndAligned = input + lengthAligned;
    const double* const inputEnd = input + length;

    // Each iteration of the loop computes 16 polynomials
    while( input < inputEndAligned )
    {
        // Load 16 input numbers
        const __m256d x0 = _mm256_loadu_pd( input );
        const __m256d x1 = _mm256_loadu_pd( input + 4 );
        const __m256d x2 = _mm256_loadu_pd( input + 8 );
        const __m256d x3 = _mm256_loadu_pd( input + 12 );
        input += 16;

        // a * x + b
        __m256d r0 = _mm256_fmadd_pd( av, x0, bv );
        __m256d r1 = _mm256_fmadd_pd( av, x1, bv );
        __m256d r2 = _mm256_fmadd_pd( av, x2, bv );
        __m256d r3 = _mm256_fmadd_pd( av, x3, bv );

        // x * ( a * x + b ) + c
        r0 = _mm256_fmadd_pd( x0, r0, cv );
        r1 = _mm256_fmadd_pd( x1, r1, cv );
        r2 = _mm256_fmadd_pd( x2, r2, cv );
        r3 = _mm256_fmadd_pd( x3, r3, cv );

        // x * ( x * ( a * x + b ) + c ) + d
        r0 = _mm256_fmadd_pd( x0, r0, dv );
        r1 = _mm256_fmadd_pd( x1, r1, dv );
        r2 = _mm256_fmadd_pd( x2, r2, dv );
        r3 = _mm256_fmadd_pd( x3, r3, dv );

        // Store 16 output numbers
        _mm256_storeu_pd( output, r0 );
        _mm256_storeu_pd( output + 4, r1 );
        _mm256_storeu_pd( output + 8, r2 );
        _mm256_storeu_pd( output + 12, r3 );
        output += 16;
    }

    // Each iteration of the loop computes 4 polynomials
    while( input < inputEnd )
    {
        // Load 4 input numbers
        const __m256d x0 = _mm256_loadu_pd( input );
        input += 4;
        // a * x + b
        __m256d r0 = _mm256_fmadd_pd( av, x0, bv );
        // x * ( a * x + b ) + c
        r0 = _mm256_fmadd_pd( x0, r0, cv );
        // x * ( x * ( a * x + b ) + c ) + d
        r0 = _mm256_fmadd_pd( x0, r0, dv );
        // Store 4 output numbers
        _mm256_storeu_pd( output, r0 );
        output += 4;
    }
}

Or if you don’t have FMA, replace
_mm256_fmadd_pd( a, b, c ) with _mm256_add_pd( _mm256_mul_pd( a, b ), c ) everywhere. Ideally, by making an inline function which does that.
If your arrays aren’t that long, just remove the first while() loop from the function, and only leave the second one.
If you really need assembly for some reason, compile the C++ and copy-paste, GCC output seems pretty good. But note assembly code is OS-specific. Windows ABI conventions specify that some of these vector registers are non-volatile. On Windows, a function which uses them needs to backup old content to the stack, and restore before the ret instruction.
